# postgres: ERROR: permission denied to create database even though user has permission

Tags: postgresql

```
                            List of roles
Role name    |     Attributes     |    Member of     |     Description
-------------+--------------------+------------------+----------------
my_role | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {} | 
my_user |                                                | {my_role} |
```

So, now I login as my_user successfully using psql. I try to create 
a database and it fails with error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied to create database
```

Any clue? I am not new to database but surely not an expert 
postgres db admin.

EDIT: createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user. If this helps?

Comment: What role are you logged in as? What database are you logged into? Are you issuing a `createdb` command from the command line? Are you supplying a -U flag if so?

Comment: @bma: psql -h <hostname> -U my_user -d defaultdb -W, then I enter the password and am able to successfully login.

Comment: @KnowledgeHungry If you `SET ROLE my_role` then try the `CREATE` does it work then? If so, you probably created the role as `NOINHERIT`.

Comment: @CraigRinger - my_user is a user belong to my_role ROLE. I assign the priviledge role. Are you saying, I shall include INHERIT priviledge to my_role ?

Comment: @KnowledgeHungry No, I'm saying `SET ROLE myrole; CREATE DATABASE ...` and see what happens. `INHERIT` should be the default, so if you did *not* specify `NOINHERIT` when creating the role that isn't the problem.

Comment: @CraigRinger - Whoa, Worked